# how to program in python for auto incrementing a number on each function call

Tags: python

I defined a function in that there is a variable `num` assigned 1000 and `increment` variable for incrementing the num by one. When it is called for the first time it increments by one and shows the value 1001 but when it is called again it shows the same value 1001 but it should show 1002, 1003 on every call

```
def number():
    num = 1000
    increment = num +1
    return increment


print(number())
```

Comment: move `num = 1000` out of the function, otherwise `num` is always getting reset and `increment` is always going to return `1001`

Comment: Write num = 1000 outside the function.

Comment: num =1000 outside the function also giving output 1001 on every function call but it is not auto incrementing

Comment: With `num = 1000` declared outside the function, also declare it inside with `global num` before using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the excellent answers already posted, you can also do this using a closure:

```
def incrementor():
    info = {"count": 999}
    def number():
        info["count"] += 1
        return info["count"]
    return number

number = incrementor()

>>> number()
1000
>>> number()
1001
>>> number()
1002
```

(The dict is a bit clumsy, but you can't do it with a simple variable name, at least without using Python 3's `nonlocal` keyword, which to me feels even more clumsy. This particular example I guess wouldn't be considered very Pythonic - but it's an option, and you will see genuine uses for similar patterns in other Python code.)

Answer (score 5):

Python allows to attach attributes to a function (after all it is an object of class `function`).

So you can avoid a global (or non local) variable this way:

```
def number():
    if hasattr(number, "num"):
        number.num += 1           # increment if not first call
    else:
        number.num = 1000         # initialize on first call
    return number.num
```

Demo:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
        print(number())
```

displays as expected:

```
1000
1001
1002
1003
1004
1005
1006
1007
1008
1009
```

And there is no risk of clash with another use of a global variable...

---

But beware. After one night, I realized that while it is what you asked for, this is an anti pattern. This is a stateful function in an OOP language, yerk...

State is supposed to be holded in *objects*, and *functions* are supposed to be stateless. You can break this rule, but it could confuse future readers of that code (even you...). So please don't.

Answer (score 3):

You should define `num` outside the `number` function, and declare it as a global variable inside the function so that you can reference it and update its value after incrementing it:

```
num = 1000
def number():
    global num
    num += 1
    return num

print(number())
print(number())
print(number())
```

This outputs:

```
1001
1002
1003
```

Alternatively, you can define a class with an instance variable that holds the current value and a method that increments it:

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def increment(self):
        self.value += 1
        return self.value
```

so that:

```
number = Number(1000)
print(number.increment())
print(number.increment())
print(number.increment())
```

would also output:

```
1001
1002
1003
```

That makes the usage somewhat verbose, however. A simpler method would be to to make `value` a class variable and override the `__new__` method of the class:

```
class number:
    value = 1000
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.value += 1
        return cls.value
```

so that:

```
print(number())
print(number())
print(number())
```

would output:

```
1001
1002
1003
```

Answer (score 1):

(Sorry for being late to the party)
A good choice for something like this might be to use a generator.

An example:

```
def number():
    num = 1000
    while True:
        yield num
        num = num + 1
```

which is probably the most similar to what you already have. Assign the generator to a variable and call next to get incrementing values from it:

```
num = number()

for i in range(10):
    print(next(num))
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

There is a function in standard Python library for this purpose.
As [someone mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53110872/6732606) to do this with a generator function.
Here's how I would do something like that:

```python
from itertools import count

number = count(1000)

print(next(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def increment(state):
    state['value'] += 1
    return state['value']

state = {'value': 1000}
print(increment(state))
```

This will mutate the dictionary.

Alternatively

```
def increment (number):
    global number
    number += 1
    return number

number = 1000
print(increment(number))  # 1001
print(increment(number))  # 1002
print(increment(number))  # 1003
```